# How to block all incoming and outgoing traffic except outgoing of 80 port and 443 in ufw?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I need to unlock only outgoing 443 and 80 port, only for navigate through internet, actually im using the rules:

```
ufw default deny incoming
ufw default deny outgoing
ufw allow out from any to any port 443 proto tcp
ufw allow out from any to any port 80 proto tcp
ufw enable
```

But unfortunally ufw blocks all internet, and the pages does not load.
Do you have any solution to my problem or another alternative?

Note: With CSF config server firewall, is not necessary the incoming traffic in the 443 and 80 ports for connect to internet only the outgoing 443 and 80, but in ufw how i can do it?

Comment: You probably mean outgoing *to* those ports,

Comment: exactly, that's is i need vonbrand!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo ufw enable
$ sudo ufw status numbered
$ sudo ufw delete #<- (insert the line number you want to delete here)
$ sudo ufw default deny incoming
$ sudo ufw default deny outgoing
$ sudo ufw allow out on eno1 to any port 443
$ sudo ufw allow out on eno1 to any port 80
$ sudo ufw allow out on eno1 to any port 53
$ sudo ufw allow out on wlp3s0 to any port 53
```

- replace `eno1` with your own ethernet name
- replace `wlp3s0` with your own wifi name
- the command `ifconfig` will show you the names of your own devices

Answer (score -1):

Remove All Ports one by one by typing:

```
sudo ufw delete allow 'PORTNUMBER'
```

Then allow port 80 and 443 by typing:

```
sudo ufw allow '80'
sudo ufw allow '443'
```

Comment: can i disable all ports using wildcards?
`ufw delete allow '*'`

Comment: `sudo ufw allow '80'` it specify outgoing only, or is for both in and out?